# Lodash forEach not iterating over whole object if iteratee function returns false

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js, lodash

I am doing a plain lodash forEach on an object like this -

```
_.forEach({a:'a', b:'b'}, (value) => {
    console.log(value);
    return false;
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/abduxr0n/

This is giving `a` as output instead of `a b`. Am i missing something? Isnt lodash forEach supposed to run on the whole object irrespective of the return value of the iteratee function? What am i missing? Please help.

Comment: Why are you returning `false` from the callback? What purpose is it for?

Comment: this was just an example. my iteratee was something like (item => condition (item) && items.push(item)) 
i didnt realise that iteratee functions may exit iteration early by explicitly returning false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are returning false from the loop, which short circuits the execution:

https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#forEach

> Iteratee functions may exit iteration early by explicitly returning false.

Answer (score 0):

The whole purpose of the `return` statement in JavaScript is to exit a function and return a value from the function. With a `forEach` loop, either in plain JS or in lodash, you don't need a `return` statement to continue looping - the function is executed and then the next iteration begins. Removing your `return` statement will make your code work:

```js
 

_.forEach({ a: "a", b: "b" }, value => console.log(value));
```

```html
 

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.core.js"></script>
```